# Rails. Mailing with per second quota (amazon ses)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email

I have 'Maximum send rate' quota on Amazon-SES service, which means the maximum number of emails that I can send per second.
What is the best way to organize my mailing in Ruby on Rails considering this quota?

Comment: Now I use https://github.com/tobi/delayed_job and save last recipient id in job task. So I have one task that send batch of mails and then reschedule. If error occurs, I reschedule task in a few seconds. But I think this is not good solution and now I don't try it in production.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, queue them and schedule a batch process to consume from this queue and send them in a timely way, considering the quota. I haven't worked with queues in RoR but I believe there are some solutions out there. Worst case scenario, queue them on the database. 
One point you should consider is the batch is not fast enough to fullfil all the mailing requestes he receives. You might them notify the admin, drop or persist the mailing for further attempt. If notified you can buy more throughput from Amazon or something like that.

Comment: Thank you. You mean something like http://www.rabbitmq.com/ ? What's the use-case of this queues? I mean that in this case I need to send one mail per task or batch of mails?

Comment: Mikhail, the solution you commented on your original post didn't look that bad. Why not try in production? Since my answer I started using this Amazon SES myself. I also have this quota, but apparently Amazon adapts and delays my requests by itself. Because I send batch emails at a higher rate but I don't get exceptions...